# Flex StackView if statement

Tags: apache-flex

I am having trouble trying to set `params` for a submit to `httpservice` function, i have 2 `viewstacks` : the first is for viewing and the second is for editing.

So what i am trying to achieve is in the save function. It will check what the current viewstack content is: if its not equal to `edit` then the params will equal to a golobal value. Please see below for the code, thank you advance

```
protected function saveUpdateCompany(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var industcurrent:Object = this.StackIndustry.selectedChild;
        PostCompanyUpdate.cancel();
        PostCompanyUpdate.url = "http://xxxx"
        var params:Object = new Object();
        params.CompanyName = companyNameForm.text;
        params.CompanyAddress = companyAddressForm.text;
        //params.CompanyCountry = companyCountryForm.selectedItem.CountryID;
        if (industcurrent == 'EditIndustry') {
            params.CompanyIndustry = this.companyIndustryForm.selectedItem.IndustryID;
        } else {
            params.CompanyIndustry = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.puteditIndustryID;
        }`enter code here`

<mx:ViewStack id="StackIndustry" width="100%" height="20">
            <s:NavigatorContent id="ViewIndustry" width="100%" label="viewIndustry">
                <s:HGroup width="100%">
                <s:TextInput id="CompanyIndustry" width="100%" enabled="false"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="EditIndustry" width="100%" height="100%" label="editIndustry">
                <s:HGroup width="100%">
                <flextras:AutoCompleteComboBox id="companyIndustryForm" width="85%"
                                               autoCompleteCursorLocationOnSelect="true"
                                               autoCompleteEnabled="true"
                                               autoCompleteHighlightOnFocus="true"
                                               autoCompleteResetIndex="-1"
                                               autoCompleteSelectOnEnter="true"
                                               autoCompleteSelectOnEnterIfEmpty="true"
                                               editable="false" enabled="true"
                                               labelField="IndustryEn"
                                               prompt="Edit Industry"
                                               selectedIndex="-1"/>
                    <s:Button width="15%" label="Cancel" click="CancelEditIndustry(event)" fontSize="8"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="EditIndustryEnable" width="100%" label="viewIndustry">
                <s:HGroup width="100%">
                    <s:TextInput id="CompanyIndustryEnable" width="90%" text="{CompanyIndustry.text}" enabled="false"/>
                    <s:Button width="10%" label="Edit" click="EnableEditIndustry(event)"/>
                </s:HGroup>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
        </mx:ViewStack>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
this.StackIndustry.selectedChild
```

gives you an element of the type NavigatorContent.

In this statement:

```
if (industcurrent == 'EditIndustry')
```

You are comparing a string with an object, which is not a valid comparison. In order to fix this, industcurrent must contain the id of the object. So, you should add:

```
var industcurrent:Object = this.StackIndustry.selectedChild.id;
```